# How to choose the estimation algorithm for the findHomography() function?

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, homography, ransac

In OpenCV, Why choose RANSAC instead of LMeDS or RHO? What advantages and disadvantages does each have? In which cases should each one be chosen?

This question came up when I read the tutorial "Features2D + Homography to find a known object"

Thanks in advance

Comment: RHO is actually PROSAC (see https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/doxygen/opencv_3.2.0/group__calib3d.html ) this is RANSAC except that the selection of points is informed by prior information instead of going full random. It is supposed to be better (for my case use, it was indeed more stable).

Comment: Thanks for the comment